# How can I get output data from this webpage using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, web-crawler

I'm trying to obtain the geographic distance between two addresses using this website: http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between.htm

I want to be able to go to the page, enter two addresses, click "Show", and then extract the "Distance as the Crow Flies" and "Distance by Land Transport" values and save them to a dictionary.

Is there any way to get the ouptut data(distance) from this a webpage, i am not familiar with html so I am not sure where the output is.  I have input the data, below is my code for reference.

webpage source code: I am not able to decipher

```
<tr>
<td align="right">From 
    <input name="pointa" type="text" value="" size="22" onkeypress="autocompletea(this.value, event)" /></td>
<td><div align="center">to</div></td>
<td><input name="pointb" type="text" value="" size="22" onkeypress="autocompleteb(this.value, event)"/></td>
<td><p role="button" tabindex="0" class="fmtbutton" onkeypress="findaandb(document.forms['inp']['pointa'].value,document.forms['inp']['pointb'].value);" onclick="findaandb(document.forms['inp']['pointa'].value,document.forms['inp']['pointb'].value);">&nbsp;Show&nbsp;</p>
  <label></label></td>
</tr>
```

my code:

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser

text = """ web input"""

browser = Browser()
browser.open("http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between.htm")

browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser['pointa'] = 'San Diego, Usa'
browser['pointb'] = 'San Francisco, Usa'

response = browser.submit()

content = response.read()

result = re.findall(r'dist', content)
print result[5]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: That web form calls a Javascript function, `findaandb`. Presumably that function is defined in either an inline `script` tag or an external `.js` script file, and it probably modifies the existing page rather than downloading a new page. So, you can't just read the new page, because there isn't one to read.

Comment: You could use something like `selenium` to drive a real browser, or embed a JavaScript interpreter and run it headless, or read the JavaScript code and try to manually port it to Python, or various other possibilities, but there's nothing easy that's going to work here.

Answer (score 0):

This page makes heavy use of javascript which mechanise does not handle as a browser would.

If you inspect the source you can see it using several apis, and calculations, for instance using the main api and an as the crows fly calculation you could get distance this way

```
import requests
import math
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def distance_on_unit_sphere(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    "src: http://www.johndcook.com/python_longitude_latitude.html"
    degrees_to_radians = math.pi/180.0

    phi1 = (90.0 - lat1)*degrees_to_radians
    phi2 = (90.0 - lat2)*degrees_to_radians
    theta1 = long1*degrees_to_radians
    theta2 = long2*degrees_to_radians
    cos = (math.sin(phi1)*math.sin(phi2)*math.cos(theta1 - theta2) + 
           math.cos(phi1)*math.cos(phi2))
    arc = math.acos( cos )
    return arc * 3960 # To get the distance in kilometers, multiply by 6373 instead

def main():
    r = requests.get('http://www.freemaptools.com/ajax/getaandb.php?a=Sydney_Australia&b=Melbourne_Australia&c=1317')
    xml = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    lat1 = float(xml.markers.findAll('marker')[0]['lat']);
    lng1 = float(xml.markers.findAll('marker')[0]['lng']);
    lat2 = float(xml.markers.findAll('marker')[1]['lat']);
    lng2 = float(xml.markers.findAll('marker')[1]['lng']);

    print distance_on_unit_sphere(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There's a `haversine` package that could simplify/abstract the `distance_on_unit_sphere` a bit: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haversine

Comment: Thanks everyone for the inputs